# Error occured When Installing SQL Server Management Studio Express on Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, installation, windows-7, ssms

SQL Server Management Studio Express installation on Windows 7 computer, suddenly a message pops up prompting that the installation is failed because of unexpected error 29506.

After several tries, the error still occurs.

[image: unexpected error 29506]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the instructions  for  unexpected error 29506.

Step 1: Run Command Prompt as administrator.
Point to the location of cmd.exe and right-click it to run as administrator.

Windows 7 (64): C:/Windows/SysWOW64/cmd.exe
Windows 7 (32): C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe

Step 2: Locate the directory of SQL Server Management Studio Express installation file with command.

Step 3: Type command "msiexec" and press Enter. A prompting dialog will appear and show the details about what command "msiexec" can do. Click OK.

Step 4: Input command below and press Enter to launch SSMS setup program.
msiexec /i SQLServerxx_SSMSEE.msi /gf

In the following, you just need to install SSMS as usual on Windows computer until it is finished. It will be successfully installed on your computer.

Please let me know if you have any questions.